# ansible-playbook --limit not working with overlapping host aliases

Tags: ansible

im having a problem limiting Ansible to work only with a specific host

my inventory file looks like this:

```
[staging-docker-containers]
app1 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2222  
app2 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2223  
app3 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2224  

[staging-other-servers]
app1 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2225  
app2 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2226  
app3 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2227
```

when i run the follow command

```
ansible-playbook --limit="staging-docker-containers:app3"  my-playbook.yml -i staging
```

it ignores the limit command and tries to connect to app3 under the `staging-other-servers` group, and not to app3 under `staging-docker-containers` group.

Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same host in different groups.
But you can't have different hosts under the same name.
If you define same host variables for the same host in different places, the latter have priority.
So you inventory actually becomes:

```
[staging-docker-containers]
app1
app2
app3

[staging-other-servers]
app1 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2225
app2 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2226
app3 ansible_host=host.domain.com ansible_ssh_port=2227
```

Comment: Im trying to use host aliases to map specific role to a spesific host, like i showed im my example, do you have a suggestion on how to do that?

Comment: @Urban48 i'm not sure what are you trying to achieve... Usually you want to make different inventory files for staging/production with the same group names, and assign specific roles inside your playbook for specific groups/hosts using `hosts:`.